# Parse SQL Insert statement and get all string values between N'VALUE'

Tags: c#, regex, str-replace, regexp-replace

I have a large SQL Server insert script

```
INSERT [dbo].[Table] ([Key], [Name], [Value], [Module]) 
VALUES (1, N'Product', N'Value 1', N'Value 2')
```

Now I need to parse this large file, line by line and for each value that is NVARCHAR `N'VALUEHERE'` I want to replace it with some custom info I fetch from a database.

If this is my script:

```
INSERT [dbo].[Table] ([Key], [Name], [Value], [Module]) 
VALUES (1, N'Product', N'Value 1', N'Value 2')
```

After I parse it I want to update it to:

```
INSERT [dbo].[Table] ([Key], [Name], [Value], [Module]) 
VALUES (1, N'Product Changed', N'Value 1 with some custom info', N'Value 2 with different info')
```

Of course the real scenario is a bit different.

In big, I want to fetch all nvarchar values and for each value that starts with `N'` get that value from single quotes, do some operation on it and update it with the new value, then move to next `N'` and so on.

My question:

How can I fetch every single value between quotes `N'VALUE'` change that value and replace with the new value `N'CHANGED'`?

```
string line = null;


StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(@"c:\script.sql");  
while((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)  
{  
       // work with `line` here to get each value 
}
```

One more issue, how do I fetch the value if it's something like:

```
 `N'Jimm''s device is broken'`
```

Comment: Just update the database afterwards.

Comment: As I mentioned the scenario is a bit different, The info coming from a rest api therefore I need to do it with C#. Sure this will have been great but I don't have access to db directly where I will fetch the info from

Comment: Is the question just how to update a text file and replace the values, or does it involve getting the data back into the database?

Comment: @Noel I need to update the SQL script at this point

Comment: Are you just appending some value to every value that's in quotes? Or is the replacement supposed to be different for every value?

Comment: I removed the sql tag because this has nothing to do with SQL.  It is about transforming a text file.

Comment: Use the regex replace overload that takes a delegate then have your conditional logic inside the delegate to get whatever the appropriate replacement text is

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I read and replace Strings line by line in a Text File?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32274427/how-can-i-read-and-replace-strings-line-by-line-in-a-text-file)

Comment: Have you looked at [`TSqlParser`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sqlserver.transactsql.scriptdom.tsqlparser?view=sql-dacfx-140.3881.1)? There are several other results if you use <your favorite search engine> to search for `tsql parser`. That would be the right way to avoid getting lost in comments, quoted strings, ... in the DML.

Comment: One way is to create a string array : string[] valuesArray : {"1", "N'Product'", "N'Value 1'", "N'Value 2'"};  Then create a string values = string.Join(",", valuesArray);   Finally add the string to the query : string query = string.Format("INSERT [dbo].[Table] ([Key], [Name], [Value], [Module]) 
VALUES ({0})", values);

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want to do some logic on the values between the single quotes. If you just want a simple string replacement then regex replace would be better.

You can use regex matches and their capture groups to select a pieces of the regex match. Then you can use the capture groups string index values to manipulate your original string.

```
string input = @"INSERT [dbo].[Table] ([Key], [Name], [Value], [Module]) VALUES (1, N'Product', N'Value 1', N'Value 2')";

Regex regex = new Regex("N'([^']+)'");
MatchCollection matches = regex.Matches(input);

//Loop though matches backwards so the index values don't get misaligned
for (int i = matches.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    //Get the capture group info for the content between the single quotes
    Group captureGroup = matches[i].Groups[1];

    //Replace the contents of the input string with some updated value
    input = input.Substring(0, captureGroup.Index) + SomeStringMethod(captureGroup.Value) + input.Substring(captureGroup.Index + captureGroup.Length);
}

Console.WriteLine(input);
```